# Infinite sum of expression as exponent goes to infinity

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I was messing around with this sum

$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)^{2n}}$

And started increasing exponent and getting numerical solutions for n=10...100....26572... you get the idea. So I noticed as n gets bigger, the sum seems to approach 1, i.e:

$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)^{2n}} =^{?} 1 $

Is this the case? Does the limit really converge to 1?

Comment: The first term is $1$ for all $n$; all the other ones go to zero. Now, find a theorem that allows you to swap limit and summation...

Answer (score 1):

Using the [monotone convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem), we can switch the order of the limit and the sum.

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{(2k-1)^{2n}}&=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac1{(2k-1)^{2n}}\right)\\
&=
1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac1{(2k-1)^{2n}}\\
&=
1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty 0=1\end{align}$$